# Width overwriting max-width

Tags: html, css

Why is width overwriting max-width making the boxes not responsive like they would if I used max-width alone. FYI I'm using inline styles because I'm coding for emails.

```
<table width="600" align="center" style="max-width: 600px; background-color: blue; padding: 0 10px;">
<tr>
  <td>
    <table width="550" align="center" style="max-width: 550px; background-color: red;">
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is width overwriting max-width

It isn't.

The element remains narrower than the specified max-width.

> making the boxes not responsive like they would if I used max-width alone

max-width alone lets the element be anywhere from `0` wide to `600px` wide depending on what else is influencing its width.

Setting the width to 600 means it has to be 600px wide.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'm just getting confused because if I set a max width on a div it will resize as the window gets smaller but my table does not can you please help me understand why?

Comment: @Reece — Because you set a width. If you said "Exactly 500 and no more than 500" then it will be 500. The "no more than 500" becomes irrelevant.